# Changing result of the findOne moongose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

i'm working in a node project and need help.

I have callback function, that executes the method findOne, have o result, but I can't change a property of the result.

Ex. Data

```
{
 name: "John",
 age:  30,
}
```

Ex. Callback Function.

```
 this._userRepository.findOne({}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback({ code: 404, message: "User not found" }, []);
        }

        user.name = "edson";

        return callback("", user);
  });
```

But user name not change in the return.

Ex. Result

```
{
 name: "John",
 age:  30,
}
```

Expected outcome

```
{
 name: "edson",
 age:  30,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `user.save()` before returning anything as given below,

```
 user.name = "edson";
 user.save();
 return callback("", user);
```

OR use `findOneAndUpdate()` as given below

```
const filter = {};
const update = { name :  "edson"};

this._userRepository.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {upsert: true}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
    return res.send('Succesfully saved.');
});
```

Refer https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html for further details

Answer (score 1):

are you actually trying to update the value of the `user` in your database? If so, I think you would need to call `user.save()`

Comment: Yes, I tried to save with user.save (), but did not save with the new name.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in an `async` function, then running the following code

```js
await this._userRepository.findOneAndUpdate({}, {$set: { name: 'edson' }});
```

The `findOneAndUpdate` method takes a filter and an object wrapped in a $set key. This method is a lot quicker.